# Updating UI controls from a Background Thread

Tags: c#

I have a GUI program that runs on a **Windows CE 2.0 Device**.  At one point I need to do a remote request to a Web Server that I want to do in a background Thread, the problem is that I also need to update a progress bar and a button's 'Enabled' property while this process is going on.

BackgroundWorker() is not available for some reason (it is greyed out).  How do I start a background thread and update UI controls from this Thread.

Comment: Is any form of .NET supported on CE 2.0?  I really doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Invoke method on the UI control to update it from a background thread.

See [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) for the old way of doing things on background threads.